# Need to get one by one column value from getadapter in Listview in Android

Tags: android

I have filled the listview using the code given below, but I'm unablee to get back the values from list because getadpter written an object. From the object I didnt able to get one by one column value.

Code for filling the listview:

```
String pkManifest = manifest.pkManifestNo;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> alist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        manifest_helper = new manifest_helper(this);

    cursor = manifest_helper.GetDeliveriesAgainstManifest(pkManifest);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("Deliv_Address",
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Address")));
        map.put("Deliv_Time",
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Time")));
        map.put("Deliv_Order",
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DeliveryOrder")));
        map.put("Deliv_IsCustomerPickup",
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("IsCustomerPickup")));
        map.put("Deliv_FKDeliveryStatus",
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("FKDeliveryStatus")));
        map.put("Deliv_PKDelivery",
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PKDelivery")));
        alist.add(map);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    sd = new SimpleAdapter(this, alist, R.layout.deliveries_list_row,
            new String[] { "Deliv_Address", "Deliv_Time",
                    "Deliv_Order", "Deliv_IsCustomerPickup",
                    "Deliv_FKDeliveryStatus", "Deliv_PKDelivery" },
            new int[] { R.id.tv_Deliv_Address, R.id.tv_Deliv_Time,
                    R.id.tv_Deliv_Order,
                    R.id.tv_Deliv_IsCustomerPickup,
                    R.id.tv_Deliv_FKDeliveryStatus,
                    R.id.tv_Deliv_PKDelivery });
    //selectedAdapter = new SelectedAdapter(this, 0, alist);
    //selectedAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

    ListDeliveries.setAdapter(sd);
```

Code for getting the value on onItemSelected is written like this:

```
private OnItemSelectedListener mDeviceSelectedListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2,long arg3) {
    Object o = av.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
        String keyword = o.toString();
    MessageBox("You selected: " + keyword);         
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
            HashMap result = (HashMap) av.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
            pkDelivery = result.get("Deliv_PKDelivery").toString();
            pbDeliveryOrder=result.get("Deliv_Order").toString();

            isCustomerPickup=result.get("Deliv_IsCustomerPickup").toString();
            if ("false".equals(isCustomerPickup))
            {               
                customerPickup="false";
                pbPickUp="false";           
            }
            else
            {
                customerPickup="true";
                pbPickUp="true";
            }
            launchDelivery_header(pkDelivery);

        }

    };
```

This can be done by getting the adapter value to a hash map and get it one by one